# D3 drag with .call() not allow us to trigger mouseup and mousedown

Tags: angular, d3.js

Hi I am using d3 with angular5 and I have created node to create Circle and in My typescript i am using node.call(d3.drag(){}) as well as mouseDown() event in node and mouseMove() and mouseUp() but this code will bind drag event with node and not allow to fire mouseDown() and mouseUP(). The scenerio is as follows.

1. There should be list of nodes in view part and we can create links between these nodes using mouseDown() event in one node and drag the line and mouseUp() event in another node to create links.
2. In another case, node can be draggable with mousedown+cntrl and mouseMove() and mouseUp() so.

The problem is that if i use

```
 node.call(d3.drag()
      .on("drag", function (d) {
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey) {
          simulation.stop();
          d.x += d3.event.dx
          d.y += d3.event.dy
          var svgWidth = $("#taxonomy-svg").width();
          var svgHeight = $("#taxonomy-svg").height();
          if (d.x < 40) {
            d.x = 40;
            $("#taxonomy-svg").css("left", (d.x - 40) + "px");
            $("#taxonomy-svg").width(width + 5);
          }
          if ((d.x + 40) > svgWidth) {
            $("#taxonomy-svg").width(d.x + 40);
          }
          if (d.y < 40) {
            d.y = 40;
            $("#taxonomy-svg").height(svgHeight + 5);
            $("#taxonomy-svg").css("top", (d.y - 40) + "px");
          }
          if ((d.y + 40) > svgHeight) {
            $("#taxonomy-svg").height(d.y + 40);
          }


          drawline();
          resetMouseVars();
        }
      })
      .on("end", function (d) {
        $('#taxonomyloader').unbind('mousemove');
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey) {
          var termid = d3.select(this).attr("id");
          var termid1 = termid.split("s");
          for (var tt = 0; tt < nodes.length; tt++) {
            if (nodes[tt].id == termid1[1]) {
              d.x += d3.event.dx
              d.y += d3.event.dy
              nodes[tt].x = d.x;
              nodes[tt].y = d.y;
              break;
            }
          }
          sendHttpRequestTerm(nodes[tt], "PUT");
        }
      }));
```

it always call drag and never call mouseDown() and mouseMove() which should be call on time of line creation.

Comment: [Unfortunately this is expected](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/2887). Maybe fixed in v5 but I'm guessing not.

Answer (score -1):

So to achieve this you're going to have to do a few things.

1. You need to register a `keydown` event to listen for ctrl being pressed.
2. You need to register the `mousedown` event and call `d3.event.stopPropagation()` to prevent if firing drag ctrl is currently pressed.
3. Register a `keyup` event and clear out whatever flag you set on `keydown`